# Link two servers to copy data

Tags: sql, linked-server

I'm trying to copy data from a DB in one server to a DB in another server. To copy data I know that I need to link the two servers, but nothing is working.

I followed [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782(v=sql.105).aspx) to link my two servers, but it returns me these error messages:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "MyServerToLink" returned message "Login timeout expired".
>   OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "MyServerToLink" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".
>   Msg 53, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
>   Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].

Comment: Check firewall settings.

Comment: First check in both servers **[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191464.aspx)**.

Comment: done, they both are checked to "allow remote connections"

Comment: This type of error arises when the remote DB server is OFFLINE or the login details are incorrect.